# I am getting so many errors in AndroidManifest.xml. How can I solve them?

Tags: flutter, dart

Following is my code:
the errors I'm getting are:

1. Unresolved class 'FlutterApplication'
2. Attribute android:icon is not allowed here
3. Unresolved class 'MainActivity'
4. Attribute android:launchMode is not allowed here
5. Attribute android:theme is not allowed here
6. Attribute android:configChanges is not allowed here
7. Attribute android:hardwareAccelerated is not allowed here
8. Attribute android:windowSoftInputMode is not allowed here

```
<!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
     flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
     to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="BMI Calculator"
    android:icon="@mipmap/bmi_calculator">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
             until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
             there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
             defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
            android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: you solve them: one by one, and learn along the way ;)

Comment: But how? That's the problem :)

Comment: Show your effort on what you have tried, and what errors do you get trying to solve these issues. Do not expect a ready solution for all 8 errors... show your effort.

Comment: @sourabhjambale, You can ignore these errors and go ahead with build. It will succeed.